# Trying to build pycairo on mac 10.8

Tags: python, cairo, pycairo

I have two Python installations. The one that came with the OS, and one I downloaded and installed manually, both are 2.7.

The one I downloaded manually is my default Python. `which python` returns

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`

I have already installed Cairo, again, manually.

I then downloaded py2cairo, went to the directory and ran `./waf configure`, which then returned...

```
  ./set_options
  ./init
  ./configure
Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/bin/gcc 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for gcc                         : ok  
Checking for program python              :/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python 
Checking for Python version >= 2.6.0     : ok 2.7.3 
Checking for library python2.7           : yes 
Checking for program python2.7-config    :/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config 
Checking for header Python.h             : yes 
Checking for cairo >= 1.8.10             : yes 
'configure' finished successfully (0.978s)
  ./shutdown
```

but then whey I try to do `./waf build`, i get this error

```
     ./set_options
  ./init
Waf: Entering directory '/Users/jose/Downloads/pycairo-build'
  ./build
  src/build
[7/9] cc: src/surface.c -> ../pycairo-build/default/src/surface_2.o
In file included from ../pycairo-1.8.10/src/surface.c:1360:
/usr/local/include/cairo/cairo-xlib.h:44:22: error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ../pycairo-1.8.10/src/surface.c:1360:
/usr/local/include/cairo/cairo-xlib.h:49: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/local/include/cairo/cairo-xlib.h:56: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/local/include/cairo/cairo-xlib.h:69: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘Drawable’
/usr/local/include/cairo/cairo-xlib.h:73: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/local/include/cairo/cairo-xlib.h:77: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘cairo_xlib_surface_get_drawable’
/usr/local/include/cairo/cairo-xlib.h:79: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/local/include/cairo/cairo-xlib.h:82: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
Waf: Leaving directory `/Users/jose/Downloads/pycairo-build'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1): 
    {task: cc surface.c -> surface_2.o}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The X-Windows files are in "/usr/X11R6". If you do not have that directory, you do not have the X-Windows development package installed.

https://trac.macports.org/wiki/InstallingMacPorts#a2.InstallXWindowsX11

Comment: Thanks, but I already have X11 installed, still doesn't work...do i need to link it?

Comment: X11 SDK is part of Apple's Developer Tools installer, now known as Xcode Tools(https://developer.apple.com/xcode/).
So have you installed Xcode with all available options in it????

Comment: Yep, that did it. I did have it installed, but the move to Mountain Lion uninstalled it. So I did it again and it worked!! Thanks.