# Failed to build pycairo on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: osx-mavericks, x11, cairo, pycairo, xquartz

Trying to install py2cairo-1.10.0 on Mac OS X 10.9. Configure went fine, then when I go to run `$ ./waf build` I get the following:

`/usr/local/include/cairo/cairo-xlib.h:44:10: fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found`

I see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429564/trying-to-build-pycairo-on-mac-10-8) that I need to have X11 installed, but since X11 is no longer included with OS X, I can't use that solution. I do have the latest version of XQuartz installed, but that doesn't seem to help anything.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this? Thanks!

UPDATE: Build and install working fine now, but still can't get it to import. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try `configure CFLAGS="-I/opt/X11/include"`

Comment: No luck - `No function CCFLAGS=-I/opt/X11/include defined`

Comment: Ok, inline variables are not supported then. Try `export C_INCLUDE_PATH="/opt/X11/include:$C_INCLUDE_PATH";` before configuring.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work! Still can't get it to import though when I go to test. I don't understand why installing pycairo has to be such an ordeal.